# Define a fallback for GTK 3 "@define-color"?

Tags: css, gtk3

GTK 3 uses a CSS-like language, but introduces "@define-color" to add named colours.

What I want to do is theme an app with its own CSS file for a few overrides, but take values from Adwaita (or compatible themes) where they've been named. The most obvious case is "@selected_bg_color". If it doesn't exist then I want to fall back to a fixed value.

In CSS, if a rule isn't understood then it is ignored and the previous applicable rule is used. I hoped that this would work in GTK's CSS by using something like:

```
  border: 2px solid #123456;
  border-color: @some-named-colour-from-adwaita;
```

This works for Adwaita and compatible themes, but for themes that don't contain the named colour then I get black instead of #123456. The themeing engine doesn't go "I don't know '@some-named-colour-from-adwaita' therefore ignore it", it goes "I don't know '@some-named-colour-from-adwaita' therefore use black".

Is it possible to do fallback colours in GTK CSS? (whether it is with override rules, conditional colour definitions, or with something else)

Comment: Have you found a solution to this @IBBoard? My thinking is that one can split their CSS in two, one containing only color definitions and another containing the rules that use them, and then load the first CSS with `GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_FALLBACK` priority to guarantee that the definitions are present but let themes (supposedly including Adwaita) to override them.

Comment: No, I never resolved it. And I've given up with GTK app development. The most i do is recolour Adwaita, which doesn't have any access to GTK constants. It sounds like it might work, but there's also a reasonable chance that it will just do the same behaviour but across separate files.